# Checking multiple array elements in if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a simple tic tac toe game, and I'm trying to check for different win states. The different tiles are set up in an array, so to check for a win for the three top spaces I have

```
if (tableArr[0].hasClass('userTaken') && tableArr[1].hasClass('userTaken') && tableArr[2].hasClass('userTaken')){
    select(); //ends game
}
```

I'm looking for a way to shorten this, I tried `tableArr[0,1,2].hasClass('userTaken')` but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this, but you'd also need to slice the array too. As an example:

```
tableArr.slice(0, 3).every(x => x.hasClass('userTaken'))
```

So, take the first three elements of the array using `slice`, then `every` checks that the test passes for each of them.

Of course, if this is tic, tac, toe, you'll need to check diagonals too, which is trickier using `.slice`. You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this too, e.g.

```
[0,1,2].map(idx => tableArr[idx]).every(x => x.hasClass('userTaken'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could check if some element doesn't have the class with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```
tableArr.slice(0, 3).some(x => !x.hasClass('userTaken'))
```